# Does Java´s BufferedReader leaves bytes in its internal buffer after a readline() call?

Tags: java, file, sockets, transfer

I´m having a problem, in my server, after I send a file with X bytes, I send a string saying this file is over and another file is coming, like

```
FILE: a SIZE: Y\r\n
send Y bytes
FILE a FINISHED\r\n
FILE b SIZE: Z\r\n
send Z byes
FILE b FINISHED\r\n
FILES FINISHED\r\n
```

In my client it does not recive properly.
I use readline() to get the command lines after reading Y or Z bytes from the socket.
With one file it works fine, with multiple files it rarely works (yeah, I dont know how it worked once or twice)

Here are some code I use to transfer binary

```
public static void readInputStreamToFile(InputStream is, FileOutputStream fout,
        long size, int bufferSize) throws Exception
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    long curRead = 0;
    long totalRead = 0;
    long sizeToRead = size;
    while(totalRead < sizeToRead)
    {
        if(totalRead + buffer.length <= sizeToRead)
        {
            curRead = is.read(buffer);
        }
        else
        {
            curRead = is.read(buffer, 0, (int)(sizeToRead - totalRead));
        }
        totalRead = totalRead + curRead;
        fout.write(buffer, 0, (int) curRead);
    }
}





public static void writeFileInputStreamToOutputStream(FileInputStream in, OutputStream out, int bufferSize) throws Exception
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    int count = 0;
    while((count = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
    {
        out.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }
}
```

just for note I could solve replacing readline to this code:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream ba = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int ch;
    while(true)
    {
        ch = is.read();
        if(ch == -1)
            throw new IOException("Conecção finalizada");
        if(ch == 13)
        {
            ch = is.read();
            if(ch == 10)
                return new String(ba.toByteArray(), "ISO-8859-1");
            else
                ba.write(13);
        }
        ba.write(ch);
    }
```

PS: "is"  is my input stream from socket:  socket.getInputStream();

still I dont know if its the best implementation to do, im tryinf to figure out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no `readLine()` calls in the code here, but to answer your question; Yes, calling `BufferedReader.readLine()` might very well leave stuff around in its internal buffer. It's buffering the input.

If you wrap one of your `InputStream` in a `BufferedReader,` you can't really get much sane behavior if you read from the `BufferedReader` and then later on read from the `InputStream.`

You could read bytes from your `InputStream` and parse out a text line from that by looking for a pair of `\r\n` bytes. When you got a line saying "FILE: a SIZE: Y\r\n" , you go on as usual, except the buffer you used to parse lines might contain the first few bytes of your file, so write those bytes out first.

Or you use the idea of FTP and use one TCP stream for commands and one TCP stream for the actual transfer, reading from the command stream with a `BufferedReader.readLine(),` and reading the data as you already do with an `InputStream.`

Comment: I do call readline outside this code, just didnt post because its kinda big

Comment: that´s what I am doing, I have wrapped lie this: socket´s InputStream -> InputStreamReader -> BufferedReader
I am reading from InputStream and then from BufferedReader, because I dont know to read until I get \r\n encoded in ISO-8859-1

Comment: how can I detect the \r\n bytes?

Comment: Or to summarize this answer: "yes, `BufferedReader` buffers."

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the main point of a BufferedReader is to *buffer* the data. It is reading input from its underlying Reader in bigger chunks to avoid having multiple small reads.

That it has a `readLine()` method is just a nice bonus which is made easily possible by the buffering.

You may want to use a DataInputStream (on top of a BufferedInputStream) and it's `readLine()` method, if you really have to mix text and binary data over the same connection - read the data from the same DataInputStream. (But take care about the encoding here.)

Comment: it looks like DataInputStream´s readline is deprecated: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html I might have to implement my own readLine until I get a \r\n but I dont know how to do it

Comment: It is deprecated since it uses a bit silly method of converting bytes to characters, simply treating each byte as a char with the same unicode value. They could simply have written in the API that they are reading the line as ISO-8859-1. If your file names are sent in this encoding, you can simply use this method.

Comment: Do you have to implement the protocol as shown in the example, or can you change it? If you can change it, I would propose to use a simpler format like the one from `readUTF` (and the corresponding `writeUTF` in DataOutputStream) instead.

Comment: I can change it, I just want to implement a method that reads a line ended by \r\n in an iso-8859-1 string

Comment: `DataInputStream.readLine` does nearly that: it also accepts a line ended by only `\r` or `\n` meaning your line should not contain these characters internally.

Answer (score -1):

Call `flush()` on the OutputStream after you've written data that you want to be certain has been sent. So essentially at the end of each file call `flush()`.

Comment: I know but, since I am sending files in a row I just need to call flush after I finish all files and is waiting for a confirmation, right?

Comment: thanks for the answer but any idea why it works for one file - as mentioned by @fredcrs?

Comment: Well, with a single file the stream probably closes, so the `readLine()` terminates correctly in that instance. I'd suggest actually using a `LineNumberReader` instead and using its `readLine` method.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you must flush your output stream in order to make sure any buffered bytes are properly sent down the stream. Closing the stream will equally have this process run.

The Javadocs for flush say:

> Flushes this output stream and forces
>   any buffered output bytes to be
>   written out. The general contract of
>   flush is that calling it is an
>   indication that, if any bytes
>   previously written have been buffered
>   by the implementation of the output
>   stream, such bytes should immediately
>   be written to their intended
>   destination.